# Django forms: cannot call form.clean

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Consider the following stacktrace:

```
In [3]: f.clean()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\Marcin\Documents\oneclickcos\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\shell.pyc in <module>()
----> 1 f.clean()

C:\Users\Marcin\Documents\oneclickcos\oneclickcos\mainapp\incorporate_helpers.pyc in clean(self)
    569         This checks the relations between fields, ensures consistent state, and exports bits about the state of the form that can be used in subsequent
validations
    570         """
--> 571         cleaned_data = super(IncorporateForm, self).clean()
    572         #logger.debug('IncorporationForm.cleaned_data: ' + str(cleaned_data))

    573         try:

C:\Users\Marcin\Documents\oneclickcos\oneclickcos\mainapp\incorporate_helpers.pyc in clean(self)
    402
    403     def clean(self):
--> 404         cleaned_data = super(CreateForm, self).clean()
    405         # trying to use an empty pk can result in a ValueError. Easier to expunge.

    406         if cleaned_data.get('pk', None) == '': del cleaned_data['pk']

C:\Users\Marcin\Documents\oneclickcos\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.pyc in clean(self)
    315         association with the field named '__all__'.
    316         """
--> 317         return self.cleaned_data
    318
    319     def has_changed(self):

AttributeError: 'IncorporateForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'
```

(All relevant code is shown in the trace above).

My code conforms to the examples at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other; however, it seems that BaseForm returns expects `cleaned_data` to exist.

Nowhere in the documentation do I see that it is the responsibility of user code to create `cleaned_data` before calling `clean`. What gives? Is this a bug in Django?

Error appears with django 1.4 and 1.3.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't call `clean` directly at all. You should call `form.is_valid()`.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see the docs never suggest that you call `form.clean()` directly. Most of the time (all the time?), you want to call `form.is_valid()`.

Under the hood, calling `is_valid()` leads to the `full_clean()` method being called, which sets `cleaned_data`.